# create simple delete function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I'm fairly new at PostgreSQL and I created a simple table with insert function but when I use my delete function it erase all my inserted queries any idea what might happen? I'm also using PostgreSQL v9.6 if anyone is asking

```
CREATE TABLE sample(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
sy char(9),
sem char(1)
);

CREATE FUNCTION insert(sy char,sem char)
returns void
AS
$$
Begin
insert into sample(sy,sem) values (sy,sem);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select insert('2011-2012','1');
select insert('2013-2014','2');
select insert('2015-2016','1');
select insert('2017-2018','2');

CREATE FUNCTION delete(id int)
returns bool
AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'delete from sample where id = id';
    RETURN true;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select delete(1);
select * from sample
id     sy          sem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete from sample where id = id` deletes all rows where the column `id` equals the column `id`. As this is all part of a string no parameter replacement is taking place. But there is no need to use dynamic SQL (`execute '...'`) to begin with. To avoid a clash between column names and parameter names it's recommended to distinguish them somehow. Many people to that by using a prefix for the parameter. Also: the language name is an identifier and should not be quoted. That syntax is deprecated and might be removed in a future version, so don't get used to it.

So, get rid of the dynamic SQL and rename your parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete(p_id int)
  returns bool
AS
$$
BEGIN
  delete from sample where id = p_id;
  return true;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```